# Is there documentation for web3 .request(...) method?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I created a js web3 app that sends a transaction with the final line of code:

`const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx);`

Now, I would like to send multiple transactions via web3's `BatchRequest`.

I can find documentation for web3 BatchRequest, but it involves transforming my previous line of code to something like

`const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();`

`batch.add(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.request(<unknown parameters>));`

Oddly, I can't find any documentation for the .request method, specifically it's parameters and return value. Is there any documentation for the .request(...) method?